# how to copy first 300 lines of a file in one directory to another directory?

Tags: linux

okay so here's an assignment question

```
sample_dir
    |-- admin
    |-- cambridge
    |   |-- cafeteria
    |   |-- library
    |   -- security
    |       |-- annex
    |       |-- building
    |       -- parking
    |-- faculty
    |-- history.exe
    |-- markham
    |   |-- annex
    |   |-- building1
    |   -- parking
    -- stenton
        |-- gen_ed
        |   |-- Holidays
        |   -- cars2
        -- lib_arts
            |-- english.txt
            -- match.doc
```

11 directories, 11 files

Your current directory is stenton. Copy the first 300 lines of file
~bto120/phones to a new file called phone_directory in stenton. This file
contains phone number and location information, sorted by last name, which
is the first field in each record.

And i keep getting "Please try again"

i've used

cp head -n 300 ~bto120/phones > phone_directory
or 
cp head -n 300 ~bto120/phones >> phone_directory

what am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

`cp` and `head` are two different programs.  Just run `head -300 oldfile >newdir/newfile`; leave the `cp` out.

Comment: okay i tried....   head -n 300 ~bto120/phones > phone_directory ; (since i want to copy the file into my current dir as phone_directory) doesn't work.....and i also tried head -n 300 phones > stenton/phone_directory ; as you said and it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
head -n 300 \~bto120/phones | sort > phone_directory
```

Comment: do you have the file `~bto120/phones`? or is `~/bto120/phones`(`~` sign meaning a shortcut for `home` directory in linux)? As long as you have the file from which you read the data, it should work.

Comment: okay found it ... it's actually head -300 ~bto120/phones > phone_directory

Answer (score 0):

it should be 
head -300 ~bto120/phones > phone_directory

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:
sed -n '1,10p' file1 > file2